Evaluating the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi^2\left(\frac{x - a}{b}\right)\phi(x)dx$.
While it is possible to get a closed-form solution to the integral
\begin{align*}
I_1(a, b) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi\left(\frac{x - a}{b}\right)\phi(x)dx = \Phi\left(-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right),
\end{align*}
where $\Phi$ and $\phi$ are cdf and pdf of the standard normal distribution, is it also possible to evaluate
\begin{align*}
I_2(a, b) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi\left(\frac{x - a}{b}\right)^2\phi(x)dx
\end{align*}
to a closed-form?  The software seems to suggest that it is possible (at least when $a = 0$), but how to deduce it theoretically?  When $a = 0$, I tried writing $I_2(a, b)$ to a triple integration
\begin{align*}
\iiint_V (2\pi)^{3/2}\exp(-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))dxdydz,
\end{align*}
where $V = \{(x, y, z): y \leq b^{-1}x, z \leq b^{-1}x\}$, then using spherical coordinates.  While this may work out (I haven't fully finished off the computation, but the process is quite verbose), I am wondering is there any alternative smarter way?

According to this link,
\begin{align*}
I_2(a, b) = \Phi\left(-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^{2}}}\right) 
-2\phi\left(-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right)\int_0^{\frac{b}{\sqrt{2 + b^2}}}\frac{\phi\left(-\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}x\right)}{1 + x^2}dx.
\end{align*}
Hence when $a = 0$, one indeed has the closed-form integral:
\begin{align*}
I_2(0, b) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2 + b^2}}\right).
\end{align*}

Cf. this post : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142931/how-can-i-compute-int-infty-infty-phi-leftazb-right2-phiz-dz?rq=1

@Abezhiko Thank you, this link provided the final result but I am particularly interested in how to reach there.

To save some typing, let me reparametrize $I_2(a, b)$ as
\begin{align*}
J_2(a, b) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi(a + bx)^2\phi(x)dx
\end{align*}
Differentiating $J_2(a, b)$ with respect to $a$ gives ("$\int$" means "$\int_{-\infty}^\infty$" below)
\begin{align*}
& \frac{\partial J_2(a, b)}{\partial a} = 2\int\Phi\left(a + bx\right)\phi\left(a + bx\right)\phi(x)dx \\
=& \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{2(1 + b^2)}\right)\int \Phi\left(a + bx\right)\phi\left(\sqrt{1 + b^2}x + \frac{ab}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right)dx \\
=& \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi(1 + b^2)}}\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{2(1 + b^2)}\right)\int \Phi\left(\frac{a}{1 + b^2} + \frac{b}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}u\right)\phi(u)du \\
=& \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi(1 + b^2)}}\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}{2(1 + b^2)}\right)\Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{(1 + b^2)(1 + 2b^2)}}\right), \tag{$\star$}\label{star}
\end{align*}
where we used the expression of $I_1(a, b)$ in the last equality.  It thus follows that
\begin{align*}
J_2(a, b) &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\int_{-\infty}^a\phi\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right)\Phi\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{(1 + b^2)(1 + 2b^2)}}\right)dt \\
&= 2\int_{-\infty}^{a/\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\phi\left(u\right)\Phi\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}\right)du.  \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
Now Let's derive the closed-form solution of $\eqref{1}$ when $a = 0$.  To this end, substituting the definition $\displaystyle\Phi\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}\right) = 
\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{u}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}}\phi(v)dv$ into $\eqref{1}$ yields
\begin{align*}
J_2(0, b) = 2\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{u}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}}\phi(v)\phi(u)dvdu. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align*}
It should be clear now $\eqref{2}$ can be simplified by invoking the polar coordinates transformation $u = r\cos\theta, v = r\sin\theta$. Under the polar coordinates, constraints $u < 0$, $v < \frac{u}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}$ are equivalent to $\cos\theta < 0$, $\sin\theta < \frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}$, i.e., $\frac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \frac{3\pi}{2}$, $\tan\theta > \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}$, therefore,
\begin{align*}
J_2(0, b) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\pi + \arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}\right)}^{\frac{3}{2}\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2/2}rdrd\theta 
= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}\right).
\end{align*}
This completes the proof.

Appendix
To match $\eqref{1}$ with the identity
\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi(a + bx)^2\phi(x)dx \\
&= 
\Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right) - 
2\phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right)\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}}\frac{\phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}x\right)}{1 + x^2}dx.
\tag{$\dagger$}\label{dagger} 
\end{align*}
shown in Wikipedia, $\eqref{star}$ needs to be rewritten (in a more complicated way) as follows:
\begin{align*}
 & \frac{\partial J_2(a, b)}{\partial a} \\
=& \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right)\Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{(1 + b^2)(1 + 2b^2)}}\right) \\
=& \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right)\left[\Phi(0) + \int_0^{\frac{a}{\sqrt{(1 + b^2)(1 + 2b^2)}}}\phi(t)dt\right] \\
=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right) + \frac{2a}{1 + b^2}\phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right)\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}}\phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}x\right)dx \\
=:& f_1(a, b) + f_2(a, b).
\end{align*}
It is easy to see that
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^a f_1(t, b)dt = \Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right). \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align*}
On the other hand, it follows by $\phi\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right)\phi\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}t\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\phi\left(\sqrt{\frac{1 + x^2}{1 + b^2}}t\right)$ and $\phi'(y) = -y\phi(y)$ that
\begin{align*}
& \int_{-\infty}^a f_2(t, b)dt \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^a\left[\frac{2t}{1 + b^2}\phi\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right)\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}}\phi\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}x\right)dx\right]dt \\
=& \frac{2}{1 + b^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}}\left[\int_{-\infty}^at\phi\left(\sqrt{\frac{1 + x^2}{1 + b^2}}t\right)dt\right]dx \\
=& \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}}\frac{1}{1 + x^2}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{\frac{1 + x^2}{1 + b^2}}a}u\phi(u)du\right]dx \\
=& -\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}}\frac{1}{1 + x^2}\phi\left(\sqrt{\frac{1 + x^2}{1 + b^2}}a\right)dx \\
=& -2\phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right)\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}}\frac{\phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}x\right)}{1 + x^2}dx. \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align*}
It thus follows by $\eqref{3}$ and $\eqref{4}$ that
\begin{align*}
J_2(a, b) &= \int_{-\infty}^af_1(t, b)dt + \int_{-\infty}^af_2(t, b)dt \\
&= 
\Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right) - 
2\phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right)\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}}\frac{\phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}x\right)}{1 + x^2}dx,
\end{align*}
which confirms $\eqref{dagger}$.

So, it basically involves the manipulation inside $\phi(\cdot). $ The rest is typical calculus. I have seen Owen's table and before that, he said all are routine calculations :-)

@User1865345 It is definitely not that routine to me :) I took almost the whole day to completely finish off the calculation.  But I agree that there is no too advanced machinery.

The main tools are manipulation and, as in most of the cases comes in handy, when you are dealing with integrals involving $\Phi, $ the interchange of integral and derivative. (Rest is patience!).

I believe your formula (1) is wrong. Tested it with python code that is attached to my answer.

@KurtG. As I stated at the beginning of the answer, I used a different parametrization in the answer (compared with the question).  That's probably the reason... Sorry for the confusion.

I saw that. In the first few lines of that python code I am switching to integrand1 which uses your different parametrization. The results don't match with numeric integration of integrand1 versus (1).

@KurtG. That's weird.  As you can see, my final answer based on (1) is correct (as it matches the published result, and I indeed checked my calculation very carefully again and again...)

Where was that published? I hope that this interaction makes it convincing that it is better to crunch numbers than to trust referees. The line before (1) is correct (numerically checked) but (1) should be \begin{align*}
J_2(a, b) &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\int_{-\infty}^a\phi\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right)\Phi\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{(1 + b^2)(1 + 2b^2)}}\right),dt \
&= 2\int_{-\infty}^{\color{red}{a/\sqrt{1+b^2}}}\phi\left(u\right)\Phi\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{1 + 2b^2}}\right),du,.
\end{align*}

@KurtG. Oh, that was a typo of me.  I will correct the upper bound of the integral (I didn't spot it because when $a = 0$, $a$ and $a/\sqrt{1 + b^2}$ coincide...).  Thanks for your checking!

Let $\Sigma$ be a $2\times 2$ covariance matrix:
$$\tag1
\Sigma=\pmatrix{\Sigma_{11}&\Sigma_{12}\\\Sigma_{21}&\Sigma_{22}}\,,\quad\Sigma_{12}=\Sigma_{21}\,
$$
of which the corresponding correlation matrix is
$$\tag2
\Gamma=\pmatrix{1&\gamma\\\gamma&1}\,,\quad \gamma=\frac{\Sigma_{12}}{\sqrt{\phantom{\big|}\Sigma_{11}\Sigma_{22}}}\,.
$$
The CDF of the bivariate normal distribution with mean zero is
\begin{align}\tag3
\Phi_2(u,v,\Sigma)&=\frac1{2\pi\sqrt{\phantom{\big|}\det\Sigma}}\int_{-\infty}^u\int_{-\infty}^v
\exp\left(-\frac{\Sigma_{22}x^2+\Sigma_{11}y^2-2\,\Sigma_{12}\,x\,y}{2\det\Sigma}\right)\,dy\,dx\,.
\end{align}
It is not hard to see that the relationship
$$\tag4
\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Big|}\Phi_2(u,v,\Sigma)=\Phi_2\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{\Sigma_{11}}},\frac{v}{\sqrt{\Sigma_{22}}},\Gamma\right)\,\quad}
$$
holds.
Now to the integral in question:
\begin{align*}\tag5
I(a, b) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Phi\left(\frac{x - a}{b}\right)^2\varphi(x)\,dx\,.
\end{align*}
It
can be written with independent standard normals, $X,Y,Z$ as
\begin{align*}
I(a, b) &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\tfrac{x-a}{b}\int_{-\infty}^\tfrac{x-a}{b}\varphi(z)\,\varphi(y)\,\varphi(x)\,dz\,dy\,dx\\[2mm]
&=\mathbb P\Big\{X\le +\infty\,,Y\le \tfrac{X-a}{b}\,,Z\le \tfrac{X-a}{b}\Big\}\\[2mm]
&=\mathbb P\Big\{X+bY\le -a\,,X+bZ\le -a\Big\}\,.\tag6
\end{align*}
The last equals sign holds when we assume $b>0\,.$ (The case $b<0$ is handled similarly.)
Since $X+bY,X+bZ$ are normals with mean zero and covariance matrix
$$\tag7
\Sigma=\pmatrix{1+b^2&1\\1&1+b^2}
$$
we can write
$$\tag8
\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Big|}I(a,b)=\Phi_2\big(-a,-a,\Sigma\big)\,.\quad}
$$
The correlation matrix is
$$\tag9
\Gamma=\pmatrix{1 & \frac{1}{1+b^2}\\\frac{1}{1+b^2} & 1}\,.
$$
Using the same method one can show
$$\tag{10}
\int_{-\infty}^c
\Phi(\alpha x +\beta)\,\varphi(x)\,dx = \Phi_2\Big(c,\tfrac{\beta}{\sqrt{1 + \alpha^2}},\Gamma'\Big)\,,
$$
where $\Gamma'$ is the correlation matrix
$$\tag{11}
\Gamma'=\pmatrix{1&\frac{-\alpha}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}\\\frac{-\alpha}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}&1}\,.
$$
For any $b\in\mathbb R$ there exists an $\alpha$ such that
$$\tag{12}
\frac1{1+b^2}=\frac{-\alpha}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}
$$
holds, namely
$$\tag{13}
\alpha=\frac{-1}{b\sqrt{2+b^2}}\,.
$$
With this $\alpha$ we set $c$ and $\beta$ in (10) such that
$$\tag{13}
c=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}=\frac{-a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}
$$
holds. Then we conclude from (4), (8) and (10) that
$$\tag{14}\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Big|}
I(a,b)=\int_{-\infty}^c\Phi\big(\alpha x+\beta\big)\,\varphi(x)\,dx\quad}
$$
holds with
\begin{align}
\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}&=-\alpha(1+b^2)=\frac{1+b^2}{b\sqrt{2+b^2}}\,,\\
\beta&=\frac{-a\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}=\frac{-a}{b}\sqrt{\frac{1+b^2}{2+b^2}}\,,\\
c&=\frac{-a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\,.
\end{align}

Here is some python code that can be used to check these formulas.
It also tests the formula from the other answer which was initally slightly wrong.

`
from numpy import sqrt, array, random
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.stats import norm, multivariate_normal

def integrand0( x, a, b, p ):
    return( (norm.cdf((x-a)/b))**p*norm.pdf(x) )

def integrand1( x, a, b, p ):
    return( (norm.cdf(a*x+b))**p*norm.pdf(x) )

def integrand2( x, b ):
    return( 2*norm.cdf(x/sqrt(1+2*b**2))*norm.pdf(x) )

def integrand3( x, a, b, p ):
    return( (norm.cdf(a+b*x))**p*norm.pdf(x) )

a = random.uniform(-2,2)
b = random.uniform(0.0001,20)
c = random.uniform(-1.5,1.5)

print( "Numerically checking a fix for (1) in the other answer." )
print( quad( integrand3, -10, 10, args = (a,b,2) ) )
print( quad( integrand2, -10, a/sqrt(1+b**2), args = (b) ) )

print( " " )
print( "I(a,b)" )
print( "Formula (5)  {:.12f}".format( quad( integrand0, -10, 10, args = (a,b,2) )[0] ) )
print( "Formula (8)  {:.12f}".format( multivariate_normal.cdf( array([-a,-a]), cov=array([[1+b**2,1],[1,1+b**2]]) ) ) )
cc = -a/sqrt(1+b**2)
alp = -1/b/sqrt(2+b**2)
bet = (-a/b)*sqrt(1+b**2)/sqrt(2+b**2)
print( "Formula (14) {:.12f}".format( quad( integrand1, -10, cc, args = (alp,bet,1) )[0] ) )

`

This is a nice probabilistic proof (+1)!
